# How to replace a sub-string in a larger-string that matches to an egrep?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

How can I replace /32 to /128 only for IPv6 addresses alone in below text?

```
52.222.128.45/32
172.22.187.101/32
52.222.128.248/32
2600:2000:2046:2000:3:db06:4200:23a1/32
2600:2000:2046:5800:3:db06:4200:23a1/32
2600:2000:2046:7800:3:db06:4200:23a1/32
```

desired output:

```
52.222.128.45/32
172.22.187.101/32
52.222.128.248/32
2600:2000:2046:2000:3:db06:4200:23a1/128
2600:2000:2046:5800:3:db06:4200:23a1/128
2600:2000:2046:7800:3:db06:4200:23a1/128
```

`egrep '\:[0-9a-f]{1,4}/32'` is matching the last four hex char and /32 but how can I keep the same four hex char how they but only change /32 to /128?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat /tmp/ips
52.222.128.45/32
172.22.187.101/32
52.222.128.248/32
2600:2000:2046:2000:3:db06:4200:23a1/32
2600:2000:2046:5800:3:db06:4200:23a1/32
2600:2000:2046:7800:3:db06:4200:23a1/32
$ cat /tmp/ips | sed 's%\(:[0-9a-f]\{1,4\}\)/32%\1/128%'
52.222.128.45/32
172.22.187.101/32
52.222.128.248/32
2600:2000:2046:2000:3:db06:4200:23a1/128
2600:2000:2046:5800:3:db06:4200:23a1/128
2600:2000:2046:7800:3:db06:4200:23a1/128
```

A description of the regex is here: https://regex101.com/r/FDjUct/1 Note that `%` is being used as a delimiter instead of `/` to avoid having to escape the `/` characters in the regex.

Depending on how much `sed` you are familiar with, it may be more clear to use:

```
$ cat /tmp/ips | sed '/:/s/32$/128/'
52.222.128.45/32
172.22.187.101/32
52.222.128.248/32
2600:2000:2046:2000:3:db06:4200:23a1/128
2600:2000:2046:5800:3:db06:4200:23a1/128
2600:2000:2046:7800:3:db06:4200:23a1/128
```

The above command uses [`sed` addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses-overview) to only apply the substitution of `32` with `128` on lines that contain a `:`.

Answer (score 3):

Following `awk` may help here.(As per Ed's comment changed `[0-9a-fA-F]` to `[[:xdigit:]]` in solution)

```
awk -v value="128" 'match($0,/(([[:xdigit:]]){1,4}:){1,4}[0-9](:([[:xdigit:]]){1,4}){1,3}\//){$0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) value}1' Input_file
```

I tested it in awk 4.1 version in case you have old version of it use `awk --re-interval` for above code too.

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -v value="128" '
match($0,/(([[:xdigit:]]){1,4}:){1,4}[0-9](:([[:xdigit:]]){1,4}){1,3}\//){
  $0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) value
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Nice `awk` answer with your `substr`! +1

Comment: Loved `:xdigit:` Didn't know it exists

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){7}[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}\/)32$
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qsQVDp/3/)

and embed it in your `sed` command:

```
sed -E 's@^(([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\/)32$@\1128@g'
```

where the `-E` option is used to enable Extended regex, if you don't specify this option you will have to escape the `(` and it is a pain.

- Uppercase letters in your IPv6 address will also be taken into account!
- `^`, `$` anchors are used to add constraint on your regex
- `@` is used as separator in your find/replace command and the replacement is backreference to the IPv6 and you add `128` to it as `32` is not in the group it is as if you had replaced it by `128`

**INPUT:**

```
52.222.128.45/32
172.22.187.101/32
52.222.128.248/32
2600:2000:2046:2000:3:db06:4200:23a1/32
2600:2000:2046:5800:3:DB06:4200:23a1/32
2600:2000:2046:7800:3:dB06:4200:23a1/32
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
52.222.128.45/32
172.22.187.101/32
52.222.128.248/32
2600:2000:2046:2000:3:db06:4200:23a1/128
2600:2000:2046:5800:3:DB06:4200:23a1/128
2600:2000:2046:7800:3:dB06:4200:23a1/128
```

With `awk` You can also reach a similar result:

```
$ cat testip | awk -F'/' '/^([[:xdigit:]]{1,4}:){7}[[:xdigit:]]{1,4}\/32$/{print $1"/"128; next}1'
52.222.128.45/32
172.22.187.101/32
52.222.128.248/32
2600:2000:2046:2000:3:db06:4200:23a1/128
2600:2000:2046:5800:3:db06:4200:23a1/128
2600:2000:2046:7800:3:db06:4200:23a1/128
```

where you use as field separator `/` and a similar regex, when a line matches the pattern you print the 1st field (corresponding to the IPv6 part) followed by `/128` then you jump to next line. By default you print the line.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks Ed, I learned a new thing today! I have updated my answer accordingly! I knew `[:digit:]` , `[:alnum:]`, `[:alpha:]`, etc but I had no idea there was a POSIX character class for hexadecimal digits